# Interacting with Tor cloud via python/stem

Tags: tor-cloud, python, stem

I'm new to Tor. I'm interested in setting up a Tor cloud (https://cloud.torproject.org/#get_started) on ec2, which looks straight forward. However besides surfing I want to use python, likely the stem library to control the Tor cloud. Is this possible directly? Does the Tor cloud have a ControlPort or Control Socket as mentioned in https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html. So far I haven't had much luck in finding resources or code samples on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused a little. The Tor cloud instance is not about surfing at all, and there's not too much to interact with for a Tor relay.

Exposing a Tor control port over the network is a bad idea, because the protocol is not secured and used only for local connections directly to it. To make use of it on your ec2 instance, install the controller software/stem locally and just connect to it that way after connecting to your ec2 instance using ssh.